# NSSession's dataTaskWithResult returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, session

I'm creating a function in Swift that calls the server to determine when the next weekly drawing for a contest is. I have the PHP script written that sends the difference between the current unix timestamp and the unix timestamp of the next contest. However, when I call this script it returns nil, rather than the timestamp I need. I've posted my code here:

```
func getTimeInSecondsToNextWeeklyWinner() -> Int {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: kTimeToNextWeeklyWinner);
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Response: \(response)")})

    task.resume()

    return 0
}
```

This ends up printing:

```
Response: nil
```

I would expect it to print something like this:

```
Response: 425352
```

Any idea why this would be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, check whether the server is returning the response correctly. You can check the response from the terminal or browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a server call then use URLWithString instead of fileURLWithPath. Latter is used to get local file i device.
Also check on your webservice if its returning response using PostMan